# WebRTC - Video streaming with Socket.io is not working

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webrtc

I am creating Video Streaming with Socket.io (Nodejs) And WebRTC. i think i am doing everything right but not even local stream shows up (neither remote). i am using this code for implement what i want

```
 const pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration)
 call.onclick = async () => {
    localVideo.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: true
    });
    for (const track of localVideo.srcObject.getTracks()) {
        pc.addTrack(track, localVideo.srcObject);
    }
 };
 pc.ontrack = e => remoteVideo.srcObject = e.streams[0];
 pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = e => console.log(pc.iceConnectionState);   
 pc.onicecandidate = (e) => {
    socket.emit('candidate', {
         candidate: e.candidate
    })
 }
 pc.onnegotiationneeded = async e => {
    await pc.setLocalDescription(await pc.createOffer());
    socket.emit('sdp', {
         sdp: pc.localDescription
    }); 
 }

 socket.on('data', (data) => {
    if (data.sdp) {
    pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data.sdp));
        if (data.sdp.type == "offer") {
             pc.setLocalDescription(pc.createAnswer());
             socket.emit('sdp', {
             sdp: pc.localDescription
             })
        }
    } else if (data.candidate) {
          pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(data.candidate))
      }
 })
```

And here is Server-side code:

```
 socket.on('sdp', function(data) {
  socket.broadcast.emit('data',{sdp: data.sdp});
});

socket.on('candidate', function(data) {
  socket.broadcast.emit('data',{candidate: data.candidate});
});
```

Console is clear but it does not work anyway.
So what is problem? And how can i solve it?
Thanks!

Comment: can you share the full code or link to the repository so that I can have a look? I suspect getUserMedia might be failing as you say not even local stream shows up

Comment: this is full code